# WYSIWYG Control for Winform

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am looking for a free WYSIWYG editor control to be used in a Winform application. The applications primary language is VB but using C# is also an option. To clarify I need a rich text editor control that has a formatting bar. I have looked all over the web and the only options I can find are expensive control packages that have more than I need. I am not adverse to creating my own version of this control, it would just be nice to find a free and open alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's very easy to write your own based on the RichTextBox control.

I would go that way for sure. Your biggest problem will be the icons for the edit bar.

Check [this one](http://www.workaholic.hu/temp/RTFEditor.zip) for starter.

Comment: Thank you this gave me a great starting point for building my own RichTextBox control.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But I embedded tinyMce http://peitor.blogspot.com/2010/01/winforms-html-editor-control-source.html

Answer (score 5):

In this scenario, starting with CodeProject articles seems the easiest:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/editor_in_windows_forms.aspx -- *Not my first recommendation, but perhaps of use if you want HTML.*
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextRulerControl.aspx?fid=968441&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2438044
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/eRichTextBox.aspx