# Access 2007 Memo Field and C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Well I am stumped.  I have a access DB that I need to convert to using C# winforms.  Everything was fine until I started working with the Memo fields.  Everything is in HTML and the RichTextBox in C# wont accept the data.

How can I maintain the formatting in the access database and also edit and save back to access from c#?

Have been searching Google for the last 5 hours and not really coming up with much.  How can I display the memo in C# formatted and then save it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) is a control for editing [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). So you would have to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html) the memo HTML to RTF when loading and from RTF to HTML when saving. Alternatively you could edit the memo field using an [WYSIWYG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258893/wysiwyg-control-for-winform) HTML editor control.

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample on how to do this?

Comment: I annotated the answer with links, check them out.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Also I just found this!  http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/