# TinyMCE like Richtext Editor for C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a good Rich Text WYSISYG editor for C# Winform applications? Something like an embeddable wordpad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WYSIWYG Control for Winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258893/wysiwyg-control-for-winform)

Answer (score 0):

We are using [TextControl](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/), it supports RTF, PDF DOC, DOCX an it's very easy to integrate.

Comment: TextControl is a Closed source component. It's required to buy the component to be used.Not a good stuff for all projects and and expensive requirement.

Comment: And What is the problem?, Noboby asked for a free option, Malfist asked for a good tool. In addition your proposal is Web only while Malfist said  that he needed the product for a Winforms application. He must have the freedom to choose between all options, if the selected solution is closed source or open source is his decision, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something from one of the major winforms framework people.  I use DevExpress http://www.devexpress.com/, mostly because that also gets me Coderush and Refactor Pro at the same price.

Other options are Telerik, Infragistics, etc.

These are not free, but you get fantastic customer support.  Even my non-priority questions are answered in hours, sometimes even on weekends.  By answered I mean some kind of code sample showing how to accomplish a task or work around a bug till it gets fixed.

You can also test drive them before buying to make sure you like their environments and solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/.

The download package includes samples with "asp" samples that can be "adapted" for asp.net and a lots of examples of different implementations.

In the practice this editors works like a multiline "textBox" area on the server side returting to you the html source of the control.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend http://freetextbox.com/. It's free and many browsers support it (Internet Explorer 6,7,8,9, Firefox 1,2,3, Google Chrome 1,2,3,4,5 etc.).

They also have a demo and documentation to play with on their website. The community is not really active. But there are topics about installation help and son on. By the time of writing this post the last message at the forum was placed 3 days ago.

Comment: Question was about WinForms controls. This answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Freetextbox is also no longer being maintained.