# Simple RichTextBox syntax highlighting for ini file

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I need to implement a simple ini file editor using RichTextBox. I want to show some syntax highlighting. Is there any simple libraries or easy implement method available?

I did some searching and came across this https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET but not entirely sure how to use this.

Comment: are you looking for a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258893/wysiwyg-control-for-winform ........ this RTFeditor is good. check this one.

Comment: I am working on a program that hosts and run PHP. I want to allow user to edit the `php.ini` within a simple window with some basic syntax highlighting for `INI` - so no, not a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up trying to implement my own syntax highlighting text editor and decided to include this tool in my project: http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html

This is pretty awesome and does exactly what I want. It's `a fast and light-weight Notepad-like text editor with syntax highlighting. This program can be run out of the box without installation` and supports INI files.